# iPhone: How to disable the vibrate for the notification sounds of a specific application?

Tags: iphone, notifications, vibration

I'm trying to build an application with some notifications. All is working logically:

If in my user's settings the vibrate mode is on, the phone vibrate for my app notifications
If in my user's settings the vibrate mode is off, the phone doesn't vibrate for my app notifications.
For now, I'm using the following code in order to play sound (with vibration):

```
- (void)playSound:(NSString *)soundName {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef  = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,
                                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)[soundName stringByDeletingPathExtension],
                                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)[soundName pathExtension],
                                                     NULL);
if (soundFileURLRef) {
    SystemSoundID soundFileObject;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);

    [self performSelector:@selector(disposeSound:)
               withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:soundFileObject]
               afterDelay:5];

    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef); 
}}

- (void)disposeSound:(NSNumber *)number {
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID ([number integerValue]);}
```

But, I have some others apps (newspaper apps for example) on my iPhone for which even if in my user settings the vibration mode is on, when these apps perform an notification, the phone plays a sound without vibration. How can I have the same behaviour for my app?

Thank in advance for your replies.